# Structural directive giving cannot bind property name

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying out a tutorial in a book and getting the error: “Cannot read property 'name' of undefined” from the html.

Here is the code from iterator.directive.ts:

```
    import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";

    @Directive({
        selector: '[paForOf]'
    })
    export class PaIteratorDirective {
        constructor(private container: ViewContainerRef, 
            private template: TemplateRef<Object>) {}

        @Input('paForOf')
        dataSource:any;

        ngOnInit() {
            this.container.clear();
            for (let i=0; i < this.dataSource.length; i++) {
                this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template,
                    new PaIteratorContext(this.dataSource[i]));
            }
        }
    }
    class PaIteratorContext {
        constructor(public $implict: any) {}
    }
```

Here is the html:

```
        <div class="row m-2">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="showTable" />
                Show Table
            </label>
        </div>
        <table *paIf="showTable" class="table table-sm table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Price</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <ng-template [paForOf]="getProducts()" let-item>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            {{item.name}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ng-template>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The error is coming on {{item.name}}.

Here is the analysis I did:

In the console, on the line of iterator.directive.ts, for (let i=0; i < this.dataSource.length; i++), the datasource has the Products with the name property populated.
I also tried putting an elvis operator after item: item?.name.  But the table doesn’t show the names.

Here is the call stack:

> core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined 
> at ProductComponent_table_5_ng_template_9_Template (template.html:18)
> at executeTemplate (core.js:11949)
> at refreshView (core.js:11796)
> at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13154)
> at refreshView (core.js:11819)
> at refreshDynamicEmbeddedViews (core.js:13154)
> at refreshView (core.js:11819)
> at refreshComponent (core.js:13229)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.js:11527)
> at refreshView (core.js:11848)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens.

You have a typo

```
class PaIteratorContext {
    constructor(public $implict: any) {}
                       ^^^^^^^^
}
```

It should be `$implicit`